# How to use Bogus Faker with initialization properties?

Tags: c#, faker, bogus

I have an immutable DTO that I'd like to fake with [Bogus Faker](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus/) (version 31.0.2) but the property with an overriding rule only returns what it was initialized with by the constructor:

#### Example DTO (real ones are more complex)

```cs
using Xunit;
using Bogus;

namespace SO.Tests
{
   class ClassWithInitialization
   {
      public ClassWithInitialization(string name)
      {
         this.Name = name
      }

      public string Name { get; }
   }
```

#### Example DTO Faker

```cs
   class FakeClassWithInitialization : Faker<ClassWithInitialization>
   {
      private FakeClassWithInitialization() { }

      public static CreateDefault()
      {
         return (FakeClassWithInitialization) new FakeClassWithInitialization()
            .CustomInstantiator(f => new ClassWithInitialization(null))
            .RuleFor(o => o.Name, f => f.Person.FullName);
      }

      public FakeClassWithInitialization WithName(string name)
      {
         RuleFor(o => o.Name, f => name);
         return this;
      }
   }
```

#### Example Tests

Both of the following tests fail as the Name property remains null as provided in the constructor.

```cs
   public class Tests
   {
      [Fact]
      public void TestClassWithInitialization()
      {
         var faker = FakeClassWithInitialization
            .CreateDefault();

         var testPoco = faker.Generate();

         Assert.False(string.IsNullOrEmpty(testPoco.Name)); #fails
      }

      [Fact]
      public void TestClassWithInitialization_with_overriding_rule()
      {
         var faker = FakeClassWithInitialization
            .CreateDefault()
            .WithName("John Smith");

         var testPoco = faker.Generate();

         Assert.AreEqual("John Smith", testPoco.Name); #fails
      }
   }
}
```

Although I could use Faker to generate random data for the constructor I would like to be able to use this fake instance to generate alternative versions, for instance, with a fixed Name as exampled by the second test above.

Why is this not working and are there any known workarounds?

Note: this is not the same as the question [How can I use Bogus with private setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54660453/how-can-i-use-bogus-with-private-setters)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible but I'd advise against it because the solution relies on .NET's Reflection.

There's a `new Faker<T>(binder:...)` binder constructor parameter. The `IBinder` interface is what `Faker<T>` uses to reflect over `T` to discover properties and fields that are settable. Whatever `IBinder.GetMembers(Type t)` returns is what `Faker<>` sees in `T`.

With this information, let's look at how the compiler generates an object with a `public` parameterized constructor and read-only property:

```cs
public class Foo
{
   public Foo(string name){
      this.Name = name;
   }
   public string Name { get; }
}
```

The C# compiler generates:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    // Fields
    [CompilerGenerated, DebuggerBrowsable((DebuggerBrowsableState) DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly string <Name>k__BackingField;

    // Methods
    public Foo(string name)
    {
        this.<Name>k__BackingField = name;
    }

    // Properties
    public string Name => this.<Name>k__BackingField;
}
```

The storage for the `Foo.Name` property uses a backing field called `Foo.<Name>k__BackingField`. This backing field is what we need `IBinder` to hoist into `Faker<>`. The following `BackingFieldBinder : IBinder` does this:

```cs
public class BackingFieldBinder : IBinder
{
   public Dictionary<string, MemberInfo> GetMembers(Type t)
   {
      var availableFieldsForFakerT = new Dictionary<string, MemberInfo>();
      var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
      var allMembers = t.GetMembers(bindingFlags);     
      var allBackingFields = allMembers
                              .OfType<FieldInfo>()
                              .Where(fi => fi.IsPrivate && fi.IsInitOnly)
                              .Where(fi => fi.Name.EndsWith("__BackingField"))
                              .ToList();
      
      foreach( var backingField in allBackingFields){
         var fieldName = backingField.Name.Substring(1).Replace(">k__BackingField","");
         availableFieldsForFakerT.Add(fieldName, backingField);
      }
      return availableFieldsForFakerT;
   }
}
```

Customize the `GetMembers()` method above to suit your needs. You'll need to change the code if you want to include `public` fields or properties of `T` too.

The last problem we have to solve is creating an object without specifying constructor arguments. We can do this by using `.GetUninitializedObject()` from `FormatterServices` or `RuntimeHelpers`. To do this, we'll create an extension method that extends the `Faker<T>` API as shown below:

```cs
public static class MyExtensionsForFakerT
{
   public static Faker<T> SkipConstructor<T>(this Faker<T> fakerOfT) where T : class
   {
      return fakerOfT.CustomInstantiator( _ => FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(T)) as T);
   }
}
```

With these two components in place, we can finally write the following code:

```cs
void Main()
{
   var backingFieldBinder = new BackingFieldBinder();
   var fooFaker = new Faker<Foo>(binder: backingFieldBinder)
                      .SkipConstructor()
                      .RuleFor(f => f.Name, f => f.Name.FullName());
                      
   var foo = fooFaker.Generate();
   foo.Dump();
}

public class Foo
{
   public Foo(string name)
   {
      this.Name = name;
   }
   public string Name {get;}
}
```

[image: Results]

You can find a full working example [here](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus/blob/fe28f91c7e457c2e7bd6256aafe2485043b301d7/Source/Bogus.Tests/StackOverflowQuestions/Question66444118.cs#L12). Additionally, you may find other solutions in [Issue 213](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus/issues/213) helpful.

Answer (score 4):

This seemed pretty easy to me, not sure if this has been added since the question was asked:

```
private readonly static Faker<Address> addressFaker = new Faker<Address>()
    .CustomInstantiator(f => new Address(f.Person.FullName, f.Address.StreetAddress(), f.Country().UnitedKingdom().PostCode(), f.Company.CompanyName(), f.Address.Locale, f.Address.City(), f.Address.County()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it seems to work :

```
class FakeClassWithInitialization : Faker<ClassWithInitialization>
{
    private FakeClassWithInitialization() { }

    public static FakeClassWithInitialization CreateDefault()
    {
        return (FakeClassWithInitialization) new FakeClassWithInitialization()
            .CustomInstantiator(f => new ClassWithInitialization(f.Person.FullName));
    }

}
```

I used directly the class constructor with the generator instead of using the generator with the property.

I also remove the WithName method that was not used.

Edit : Seems I misunderstood the question.
I don't know much about Bogus. I thought you could use optional parameters in "CreateDefault" method but you told DTO was complex so... There will be too much parameters.

I think you can achieve what you want with the builder pattern :

```
public class Builder
{
    private string _name;

    public Builder WithName(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public ClassWithInitialization Build()
    {
        return new Faker<ClassWithInitialization>()
            .CustomInstantiator(f =>
                new ClassWithInitialization(
                    _name ?? f.Person.FullName
                ))
            .Generate();
    }
}

var faker = new Builder().WithName("Hello").Build();
var faker2 = new Builder().Build();
```

You can delete the FakeClassWithInitialization and replace it with a classic "Builder".

Comment: Thanks @Arcord - yes I knew that would work but it doesn't help with the case where there is - for instance - a complex DTO structure with many properties. The idea of `WithName` (which is used in the second test example) is that it takes the default DTO construction and changes one aspect or group of related aspects of the DTO. I tried to keep the example simple but the actual case would be much more complex. I could, of course, just construct a new Faker in every `With...` method or replace the `CustomInstantiator` but that doesn't achieve much over creating it without Faker. Ideas?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I don't know how to solve it with the library but I think a classic builder pattern can achieve what you want. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: thanks @Arcord for the suggestion. I have gone for a similar solution using Func<Faker, T> instance variables which are then used in the .CustomInstantiator. I'd still prefer a more 'Faker' like solution so I won't accept your answer just yet and may post my alternative solution at a later date. Thanks again.